# DpiChanged event comes multiple times?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 monitors, one of them is running at 100% scale, other is 175%.

I start a window on monitor1, 100%, then move it slowly to monitor2, 175%:

I can validate DPI change with form's `DpiChanged` event:

```
DPI changed: was: 96, now: 168
MessageBox2_Resize: System.EventArgs
MessageBox2_Resize: System.EventArgs
```

However, when I moving the form back from 175 to 100:

```
DPI changed: was: 168, now: 96
DPI changed: was: 96, now: 168
MessageBox2_Resize: System.EventArgs
MessageBox2_Resize: System.EventArgs
DPI changed: was: 168, now: 96
DPI changed: was: 96, now: 168
MessageBox2_Resize: System.EventArgs
DPI changed: was: 168, now: 96
MessageBox2_Resize: System.EventArgs
```

And this messes up everything.

Important note: Form is set to be "AutoSized" by its contents. If I disable autosizing, it works perfectly.

I have used .NET Framework 4.8 for this, and `PerMonitorV2` for `dpiAwareness`.

Comment: As far as I know the DPI would be from the monitor that contains most of the Windows. However, as you auto-scale it, there is probably a conflict because after the sizing, it would change the monitor that has most of the Windows. I guess that you could disable auto scaling and manually adjust the scaling and position to avoid the problem. If would probably be useful for you to log the size (and position) too as it might help a lot understanding what is happening.

Comment: Yes. That's happening: I have an autosizing label, which dictates the size of the form. When moving between monitors, the text is reformed: at 100%, it fits into 3 lines, but on 175% it needs 4 lines which I honestly don't understand why. But due to this, it resizes the form which causes this conflict, as Windows can't decide which monitor is my form on. What's the reason a 3 line label needs 4 lines?

Comment: Well without seeing the exact case, it is almost impossible to give any suggestion... but you might be able to adjust the size, margins, paddings, min/max size so that the problem could be avoided. Obviously, text size is not exactly proportionnal to form size (or font height) for 2 main reasons : (1) Some characters like "l" would almost not vary their width when font size increase. (2) Usually size are rounded to an integer so particulary when font is small, their could be a large step between consecutive font size.   Something you might try is disabling auto-size while moving the window.

Comment: Another important thing to consider is what **version** of Windows and .NET you are using and what is your **configuration** of your application for multiple DPI monitors handling. It is well known that large/multiple DPI support was improved over the years and some options are opt-in. Typically, legacy application are not **DPI aware** so they would do bitmap scaling and don't look good if DPI is changed. **Obvioulsy**, you should provide code sample to reproduce the problem (and pictures too) as otherwise **it is mostly useless** to ask that kind of question.

Comment: The question is fuzzy about what the code does when the notification event fires.  But an obvious thing to do is to resize the form to match the active dpi.  That causes the system to re-evaluate the position of the form, it can now move back to the hi-res monitor.  In other words, you probably want to change the Location property of the form as well so the center of the form stays on the same monitor.